# How to upload and retrieve a video from s3 or local machine to Wowza Media Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, wowza

I have websites which has lots of video which is uploaded on S3 for streaming I want to upload this video on Wowza server. 
I have referred below link :
 https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?69-How-to-use-Amazon-S3-with-Wowza-Media-Server 
 but not getting any progress, if anyone has docx please share it.
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to ultimately playback the VOD assets stored in your S3 bucket on Wowza, I'd suggest following the [Standalone](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?551-How-to-use-Amazon-S3-with-a-standalone-Wowza-Media-Server-and-the-MediaCache-AddOn) or [EC2](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?69-How-to-use-Amazon-S3-with-Wowza-Media-Server) guides.  This will allow you to leverage their MediaCache technology to integrate with your S3 bucket(s) as necessary.